# Software for barcode registry

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-apps, spreadsheet, barcode

I have a fruit harvesting business that I would like to find existing, or implement software to keep a registry of scanned bin barcodes for each day, per team, and block area of an orchard.

Any given day might have a total of 500 bins picked, 250 from TeamA, 350 from TeamB, 200 from Block 1, and 150 from Block 2 and 3 lets say. Each bin has a bin card with a unique barcode and I have a bluetooth scanner that passes the value as an integer. At the end of the day I want totals from blocks and teams.

Obviously this could easily be done with Excel and macros quite efficiently but Excel won't run with macros on a mobile device (I think I'll want to go to a small format touch screen device). Google sheets and macros could be done easily too but some orchards are out of 3G reception and googles scripts are server side only.

I started to write a javascript grid based app but I think before I continue I'll ask here for more obvious ideas?

Thanks in advance, as always

Comment: If you meant [tag:android] instead of [tag:google-apps], maybe one of the [barcode inventory apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_barcode_inventory#group_34) could fit? I'm not aware that Google itself wrote one (or why you should insinst on that).

Comment: Currently, how do you identify which barcodes are used by a specific team/block? Are the barcodes new each day, or fixed?

Comment: Actually the barcodes are completely irrelevant, they would only serve as a means of preventing duplicate scans. The bin cards contain 2 peel away barcodes, one of which we are using to stick to team lists, with block labels.

Google sheets would be good for it with scripting is all I meant, but scripting needs internet connection. Android apps would be fine. I will have a look through that list but I've found most inventory apps want the user to manually enter data after each scan